# R Markdown does not display DataFrame

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am currently facing a problem that a specific data frame won´t display after executing the rmd chunk.
Unfortunately I have not found a solution yet.
I have created the rmd with the default output format: html

When I knit the rmd everything is displayed properly. The problem is just while executing the chunks.

The rmd looks as follows:

Chunk1:

`{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)`

Chunk2:

`df <- readRDS("df.rds")`

Chunk3:

`head(df)
df
tail(df)`

--None of these three lines displays the dataframe

I already changed the working directory to the directory where the datasets are placed.

I tried to generate a dataframe and display it. This worked fine

I tried to display mtcars. This also worked fine

I created a csv file, read it into R and it worked. Then I saved it as rds, read it again and it also worked.

However if I want do display the initial dataframe it does not work. I also tried to save it into another dataframe but this approach also failed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How about trying Knitr::kable(data) in the chunk. Could you provide a minimum reproducible example in your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not.. I am not allowed to share the dataset and every other dataset works fine.. The dataset has 9columns and 1512 rows. 7 columns have the datatype float/int, one is a date and the last one a string.

Comment: The chunks above are all the chunks that I currently have in the rmd. So I am just reading a rds file and try to head it.

Comment: I am able to read the rds file and show it manually in the "Global environment" section of R. Knitting also works. However if I try to head it in the rmd file (so without knitting it), it does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

readRDS() returns an R object, so if you saved a dataframe as a .rds that's what you'll get. Therefore, the question is: are you sure that df.rds is a dataframe? You can do class(df) to check and, in case it's not, you might be able to just do a as.data.frame() to make it such.

Comment: Class(df) says that it is a dataframe. However I still tried to convert it to a dataframe with as.data.frame() as you said but it still does not work.

Comment: The problem is that when I knit the code it works properly, but the interactive display function of RStudio does not show it